# Galaxy S 21 Ultra is not displaying a full text string that is displayed on other Android phones

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy

[image: Galaxy S 21 Ultra]
[image: Pixel 3]

I have only been able to test my app on Google devices and emulators. Today I got a hold of a Samsung device and I noticed the text "Your Routes" (below Tuscaloosa City and County) is only displaying "Your" on a Galaxy S 21 Ultra.

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/your_routes"
                style="@style/GreyText"
                android:layout_width="84dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:text="@string/your_routes"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/organization"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

strings.xml

```
...
    <string name="your_routes">Your Routes</string>
...
```

Comment: Why are you using fixed sizes for your text view? Can't you define the height as wrap content, and the width as 0 with an `end_toStartOf` vaue for the status? Also, what's inside your `GreyText` style? If you have no `ellipsize` strategy, then text would be cut off.

Comment: Beyond differences between devices with respect to things like font scale, users can change font scale as well. As PPartisan notes, using fixed heights dramatically increases the risk of this sort of a problem. Allow the `TextView` to have its natural height (`wrap_content`), and consider using `android:maxLines` and either `android:ellipsize` or `android:autoTextSize`.

Comment: I am new to Android Development. Thank you for the comments - I am going to do some reading, edit this question (improve the OP) and provide an answer.